# Selenium and Javascript

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to learn how to use selenium. I'm trying to work on creating script to like instagram photos; however, i'm running into a problem where xpath won't detect the image i want to click. I think this is probably due to the fact it's a javascript button.

This is a picture of the element i am inspecting. There's multiple pictures on the site and i am given the line

```
<a class="thumb-shadow" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

https://gyazo.com/558df373e6ac426f098759665fd8f918

I've tried clicking the xpath of image wrapper, but it doesn't work either. How can i click the javascript item? Are there any resources you can point me to?

Thanks

Comment: First thing, It doesn't matter whether it is a javascript button or what else. If you are able to click a button manually so you can click that button with selenium also. Second thing is please provide full Html of that button.

Comment: the highlighted row is the "button" i found from viewing the path. It's actually a photo that's supposed to open a smaller window once i press it. Okay, so i tried driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='thumb-shadow']").click(), but got no luck. If i expand the thumb-shadow class, i get this https://gyazo.com/3776510f4b40d58ef6606b4c51a1d1c1. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='thumb-shadow']/img").c‌​lick()`

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Ooh, i see how it works. So it is true that xpath can locate just about every button/item. From using xPath viewer plugin, i get id('page-content')/x:section[1]/x:div[2]/x:div/x:section/x:div[1]/x:section/x:a. Do you know how i would be able to input this iinto the driver.find_element_by_xpath?